# What exactly are Leila's Geass powers?

Tags: character, code-geass, akito-the-exiled

In Code Geass: Akito the Exiled, what exactly are Leila's Geass powers, her geass bird symbol was not red but blue:

[image]

The only character who had blue geass eyes in Code Geass universe was Jeremiah:

[image]

But Jeremiah have it inverted and we know that his geass power was to cancel geass. But what are Leila's geass, she was able to face Shin's geass order and had something to do with changing space-time continuum etc.

But what are her exact powers are all about and why her geass is not red?

Comment: i would like to point out that originally [Leila's Geass was red](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/codegeass/images/7/77/Akito-3-Img030.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20150709062959)

Comment: @Memor-X wow I completely forgot that

Answer (score 2):

One theory I've heard is due to the nature of her intent

C.C wanted to be loved
Lelouch wanted power to topple the Britannian Empire
Mao didn't want to be alone or something

They're more personal gains from the power, rather than a selfless gain, where as Leila wanted everyone to be happy.

In the case of the red geass, the geass grants the user something, rather than helping others directly, but Leilas geass, and by extent Jerimiah's geass canceller, hold more benefit for others, rather than for the user.

So it could be possible that leila's geass is blue due to her being selfless, and the geass not holding benefit for her.